# Jest config to be able to run tests using node modules source

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I have two projects:

1. App
2. A library (to share code)

On my app, I have one test using directly the source of my npm package library

`import { mockAddress } from '@xxx/library/src/entities/address';`

#### Issue

> Jest encountered an unexpected token
>
> ```
> This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.
>
> By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".
>
> Here's what you can do:
>  • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
>  • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
>  • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config
> ```
>
> option.

#### What I tried

I tried to add the folder of my library to `transformIgnorePatterns`

```
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<roodDir>/node_modules/(?!vee-validate/dist/rules)',
    '<roodDir>/node_modules/(?!@xxx/library/src)',
  ],
```

I tried to add `transform`

```
'\\.(ts|js)x?$': 'ts-jest'
```

#### EDIT 1

```
 transform: {
    'vee-validate/dist/rules': 'babel-jest',
    '\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
  },

  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!vee-validate/dist/rules|@xxx/lib/)',
  ],
```

### jest.config

```
  module.exports = {
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      isolatedModules: true,
    },
  },
  verbose: true,
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel',
  collectCoverage: false,

  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '**/entities/**/*.ts',
    '**/services/**/*.ts',
    '**/store/**/*.ts',
    '**/ui/components/**/*.{js,vue}',
    '**/ui/views/**/**.{js,vue}',
    '!src/main.ts', // No need to cover bootstrap file
    '!**/store.ts',
    '!**/*.mock.ts',
    '!**/*.types.ts',
    '!**/index.ts',
  ],
  transform: {
    'vee-validate/dist/rules': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<roodDir>/node_modules/(?!vee-validate/dist/rules)',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
  testMatch: [
    '**/*.(spec|test).(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
  ],
  roots: [
    '<rootDir>/src',
  ],
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    // Allow test environment to fire onload event
    // See https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1816#issuecomment-355188615
    resources: 'usable',
  },
  reporters: [
    'default',
    [
      'jest-trx-results-processor',
      {
        outputFile: './coverage/test-results.trx',
        defaultUserName: 'user name to use if automatic detection fails',
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest",
      "vuetify",
      "vue-meta"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },

  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your transformIgnorePatterns are mutually exclusive. There should be only one pattern for node_modules

Comment: @EstusFlask I did change of edit 1 but still the same 'node_modules/(?!vee-validate/dist/rules|@xxx/lib/)',. I'm not sure if whether I need to add <rooDir> before

Comment: rootDir won't help because it's more restrictive this way. Paths are excessive and don't take backslashes into account, `/` should be `[/\\\\]`.

Comment: You mean replace all `/` by `[/\\\\]` so it would be `node_modules[/\\\\](?!vee-validate[/\\\\]dist[/\\\\]rules|@xxx[/\\\\]lib[/\\\\])'`` ? The fact that I'm using directly the source from my lib could it be an issue ?